# What is the best architecture for modeling, on the most generic way possible, a behaviour that depends on two main types (or their subtypes)?

Tags: design-patterns, architecture

I would like youy to consider a civil engineering application whose purpose is to detect which elements, called **Crossings**, pass through certain **Holes** in the walls. The final objective is to associate a list of **Crossings** with each **Hole** element.

The **Crossings** may be of many subtypes (pipes, air ducts, equipment, etc.), as well as the **Holes** (round, rectangular, “L” shaped, polygons, etc.). The algorithm that detects if a given **Crossing** passes through a **Hole** depends both on the **Hole** and the **Crossing** subtypes. Note that, at the start of the development, not all **Crossing** and **Hole** subtypes are known.

Given the amount of possibilities, the different algorithms to implement and their varying degrees of complexity, the application architecture should allow adding newer algorithms and **Hole**/**Crossing** subtypes without much effort.

Since the detection algorithm depends on both the **Holes** and the **Crossings**, it seems artificial to have the calculation method (algorithm) built inside one or the other. This is also valid for any possible subtypes derived from these main types.

The fact that not all the exact subtypes of the objects involved (**Hole** and **Crossing**) are known beforehand makes me think of the Factory DP. However, the behaviour dependency on the subtypes ("detection algorithms") somehow confuses me while trying to apply the Factory DP here.

I have also thought on considering the “detection algorithm” as an object on its own. Then, a sort of “Factory” could be responsible for issuing a given “calculation method” depending on a specific **Hole**/**Crossing** pair. However, due to the complexity of the algorithms involved, I am afraid that the implementation of this “Factory” may turn out to be an angry herd of ancient and hairy woolly mammoths.

Summing up, my two main questions are:

- How should I model the distinction between the two “obvious” main types (**Hole** and **Crossing**) and their multiple, and mainly unknown subtypes?
- How should I model the "detection algorithm"?

These qustions should be answered keeping in mind that, in the future, more **Holes**, **Crossings** and their respective algorithms should be easily added.

Can anyone out there lend me hand on figuring out an elegant solution for this architecture problem?

Thank you

Comment: Can you give an example of algorithm to detect if a Crossing passes through a Hole? Does size matter or only shape?

Comment: Size always matters :) Just kiddin’. Here's an example for a circular hole [point (its centre), direction (its “axis”) and radius] and a pipe [list of sequential points (its centreline)].
Here's a simple (non-optimised) algorithm:
-Go through every segment S given by a pair of points from the pipe;
-Intersect S with the hole plane (given by its centre point and its direction);
The pipe intersect the hole if:
The intersection point exists AND the intersection point is inside the segment S AND intersection point is inside the sphere defined by the centre point and the radius of the hole.

Comment: So this is about detecting intersection of 3D geometrical objects. I would separate the object hierarchies and the algorithm. The concrete object like Holes or Crossing can provide inputs to the algorith but it is not a Hole's responsibility to detect of a Crossing would pass though it (tight-coupling).

Comment: are you tied to a particular language? The answer to this question hugely depends on the ways each language allows modeling.

Comment: I think you should take a look at collision detection in graphics, it might give you a good start.

Answer (score 0):

The way a domain is modeled strongly depends on what data will be required and how you're going to operate with it. Reading through your question I came up with the following conclusions, feel free to comment If I'm wrong.
 - You will have a set of algorithms that take to input parameters being a **Crossing** and a **Hole** respectively.
 - The **Crossings** and **Holes** are of multiple different kinds, some of them not currently known.

The first thing to take in account is that the information needed to represent each kind of Hole will be different. For example a circular hole and an L shaped hole won't have the same information, the first has a center and a radius while the later doesn't. This happens in a similar fashion for Crossing objects. So we should ask ourselves what would be the best representation that can take in account those differences.

If we were to model this in an OOP model an approach based on Baseclass + Inheritance might come to mind. However there are two caveats on that, the first is that as pointed out by @Lini Crossings/Holes don't exhibit behavior, they're plain data. The second is that the Baseclass won't have shared attributes with the subclasses since every kind of Crossing/Hole would be represented by different atributes and the same happens with the accessor methods, so we would have an empty BaseClass whose whole purpose would be to know whether an object is a subtype of Crossing or a subtype of Hole. Depending on the language you're working on this approach might be mandatory and IMO I don't think is a bad approach either.

If you're instead using a functional language like Clojure you might model the Crossings and Holes as dictionaries with two fields to represent the Type and the Subtype which would allow to use standard functions for accessing and modifying the data. In the end, the addition of new subtypes would be easy in both scenarios.

The second thing is that the number of possible pairings could get very high so you need a way to organize the algorithms and decide upon each pairing which one should be called in a way that allows to easily handle new subtypes. Personally I don't like making the detection algorithm a Class because is a data processing thing rather than data itself (I'm a little purist here :). My approach to this would be [multimethods](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Multiple_dispatch), which are dynamic dispatch functions. The overall idea is as follows:

- Create all necessary algorithms to process each pairing. If one algorithm can handle several Crossings or Holes you can also do so.

```
Alg1 :: (CrossA HoleA) --> Result
Alg2 :: (CrossA HoleB) --> Result
Alg3 :: (CrossB (Either HoleB HoleC)) --> Result
```

- Create a Pairing function to make the pairing process that will return a keyword used to know what detection algorithm to call.

```
Pairing :: (Crossing Hole) --> Keyword
```

- Create the multimethod. It will accept any pair of Crossing and Hole, then call Pairing and finally dispatch to the appropriate algorithm based on pairing result.

```
Detection :: (AnyCross AnyHole) --> result
```

With this approach every algorithm is isolated and the addition of new ones just require to add a new match to Pairing and Detection functions. Furthermore the addition of types and algorithms won't break your existing code due to the separation of concerns. The only drawback I can think of is that maybe this design pattern is a little bit harder to implement in an OOP language than in a functional one, but of course there would be nuances in languages of both sides.

Hope this TL;DR helps you a bit to consider the options available.